# How can I prevent showing content that is off-screen when a user "drags" mouse across viewing area?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using "overflow: hidden" on the body tag, which hides the scroll bars, but it doesn't prevent the user from click-dragging the mouse to reveal outer content when dragging to the bottom or right-hand edge of the browsing window. Here's the site:

http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/

To replicate behavior, one way (in Chrome) is to press the middle mouse button and drag down or right. In IE9, grab and drag a menu button to the edge.

Is there an application-wide way to prevent this, or is there a property or event-call that I must rework on every single element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first thought was to use the CSS clip property, and change it via javascript to match the visible parts of the body...

Comment: I couldn't seem to get CSS clip to work with the body tag. Would I need to use this on each of the sliding elements that leave the body area?

Comment: no, surround everything with a div that acts like the body, and on this div apply that CSS rule of clipping. You will also need to use some javascript to update its height + width and the clip properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting both the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` CSS properties to `"hidden"` on the element that is serving as your clipping element.

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timer loop that constantly moves back to (0,0).

```
var noScroll = function() { window.scrollTo(0,0) };
setInterval(noScroll,10);
```

Comment: I added this to my step function and it does fix it, with a side effect of a millisecond of showing the old behavior (and toggling back and forth on a drag). I also tried (unsuccessfully) using window.addEventListener('scroll',function (e) {e.preventDefault();},false). Apparently scroll doesn't have a cancel-able default behavior, which would have been ideal.

Comment: If you implement a throttle or debounce you should be able to fix the flickering.